# MIN(DATE) not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I’m using SSMS to query SQL Server 2012.  I need the record out of the NPH table with the earliest STARTDATE.  If I have a client with rows with the same startdate, I get one row. But for clients with rows with different start dates, I get no results at all.  Why is it not bringing back the min(startdate) out of the PLACEMENTHISTORY table?

```
select distinct lsf.CLIENTNUMBER
,nph.ENDDATE
,nph.STARTDATE
from legalstatusform lsf
left join PLACEMENTHISTORY nph on nph.CLIENTNUMBER = lsf.clientnumber
and (nph.STARTDATE = (select min(startdate) from PLACEMENTHISTORY x
                where x.CLIENTNUMBER = nph.CLIENTNUMBER))
where nph.ENDDATE >= '2017-05-01'
and nph.ENDDATE <= '2017-05-31'
and nph.CLIENTNUMBER = '2001'
group by lsf.CLIENTNUMBER, lsf.ENDDATE, nph.STARTDATE, nph.ENDDATE
```

This logic gives me NO results at all

If I comment out the min(startdate) logic, I get 3 rows of data for this client.  with startdates of 1/31/2017, 4/11/2017 and 5/10/2017.  So with the min(startdate) logic, why do I NOT get only line 1 with the 1/31/2017 startdate?

Comment: It can return no result, because `MIN` subquery for this user return another date (not one of this three)...

Comment: right, duh.  I misspoke. I should be getting the 5/10/2017 date, but not no results, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a subquery (and parsing the table twice) try using a CTE. The Sort may end up being just as expensive, depends on your indexing:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT lsf.CLIENTNUMBER,
           nph.ENDDATE,
           nph.STARTDATE,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lsf.CLIENTNUMBER ORDER BY nph.STARTDATE) AS RN
    FROM legalstatusform lsf
    LEFT JOIN PLACEMENTHISTORY nph ON nph.CLIENTNUMBER = lsf.clientnumber
    WHERE nph.ENDDATE >= '2017-05-01'
      AND nph.ENDDATE <= '2017-05-31'
      AND nph.CLIENTNUMBER = '2001'
    GROUP BY lsf.CLIENTNUMBER, lsf.ENDDATE, nph.STARTDATE, nph.ENDDATE)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: That works and I've never used a CTE. Now my problem is that this code will go into a report in SSRS and the Enddate is a declared parameter, which isn't working with this. Can I use a declared parameter within a CTE?

Comment: Yes, just use it as you normally would in the `WHERE` clause inside the `CTE`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, but I found another post that says you have to add a semicolon after it and it works now...wooohooo, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, `WITH` requires that you terminate your (prior) SQL statements. Not terminating your SQL statements with a `;` has been deprecated, so it's good practice to do so anyway; especially as functions are introduced that make it mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct` is almost never appropriate with `group by`.

Your problem are the conditions in the `where` clause.  These turn the outer join into an inner join.  Try this:

```
select distinct lsf.CLIENTNUMBER, nph.ENDDATE, nph.STARTDATE
from legalstatusform lsf left join
     PLACEMENTHISTORY nph
     on nph.CLIENTNUMBER = lsf.clientnumber and
        nph.STARTDATE = (select min(startdate)
                         from PLACEMENTHISTORY x
                         where x.CLIENTNUMBER = nph.CLIENTNUMBER)
                        ) and
        nph.ENDDATE >= '2017-05-01' and
        nph.ENDDATE <= '2017-05-31'
where lsf.CLIENTNUMBER = '2001';
```

Notes:

- You may need the conditions on `ENDDATE` in the subquery.
- I would window functions rather than this form of the query.
- If `CLIENTNUMBER` is a number, then `'2001'` should not have quotes.

Comment: The code you gave me gives me a result, but both ENDDATE and STARTDATE are NULL

Comment: @SheriAnderson . . . Not at all surprising.  You might want to filter by date in the subquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because your subquery with the MIN() doesn't have this condition:

```
where nph.ENDDATE >= '2017-05-01'
and nph.ENDDATE <= '2017-05-31'
```

Run just the subquery

```
select min(startdate) from PLACEMENTHISTORY
where x.CLIENTNUMBER = '2001'
```

And see if the row with the MIN() startdate matches the filters in your outer query.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I added and  x.ENDDATE >= '2017-05-01'
     and x.ENDDATE <= '2017-05-31'    and it works now!  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Darn it.  It works for writing this query, but this query will be in an SSRS report and my dates are Parameters.  Apparently I can't use declared parameters in a subquery?   When I add the @StartDate for the parameter, I again get no results. Any ideas?

Comment: No it doesn't and I see what you are saying, but I need the min(startdate) within the dates as parameters.